# Magento2: What is the function of attribute_id?

Tags: magento-2.1, database

I have installed Magento CE 2.1.7 with sample data.

In the table `catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1` of my magento database. I see

[image]

The `entity id`, I believe is unique for every product. The `attribute_id` for every product has three values, 73, 74 and 75.

Clearly, we have

`product name` for attribute_id `73`
`SKU id` for attribute_id `74`, and
`product description` for attribute_id `75`

I have the following questions regarding `attribute_id`

1. What's the exact role of `attribute_id`?
2. Why the values of `product name`, `SKU id` and `product description` are stored in this way inside the database?
3. Why the numbers 73 , 74 and 75? Why not 1 , 2 , 3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because products are stored using the EAV model, i.e. the Entity Attribute Value model, this means that any given product can have several unique atrributes assigned to it, which may or may not be true for other products, so in order to reduce storage, it is stored using the EAV.

The values themselves are arbitrary, i.e. computer-generated and actually not important to know, as you can use Magento to retrieve them by attribute code.

For more information, you can look at these pages:

[EAV explained by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)

[The Magento 2 model defined](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/attributes.html)